# Function that is always positive

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

Let $g(x) = x^6−x^5+x^2−x+3$, $−∞ < x < ∞$. Show that $g(x) > 0$
for all $x$.

My approach: 
I have considered the integration of function $g(x)$ call it $f(x)= \frac{x^7}{7} + \frac{x^6}{6}+ \frac{x^3}{3}- \frac{x^2}{2}+3x$ and was trying prove that it was increasing which therefore implies that  derivative of $f(x)$ is always positive.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I have considered the integration of function g(x) call it f(x) and was trying prove that it was increasing which therefore implies that  derivative of f(x) is always positive.

Comment: user147835, edit your question and add details on what $f(x)$ is.

Comment: Differentiate it and find the critical points (if somehow you can solve the quintic), one of them will correspond to the minimum value of g which is positive

Comment: @TavishMusic This not only requires determining the value of the root of the quintic, but also we have to show that the derivate has only one root. This could however be done with the second derivate, which has however still degree $4$.

Comment: @Peter Why must it have only root? Couldn’t the derivative equal zero at multiple points with one of them being the absolute minimum?

Comment: @TavishMusic What I mean : To be sure that $g(x)$ has only one root, we have to know that the derivate only has one root (and that $g(x)$ is positive at this point). It is of course sufficient to know all real roots. In this case, we can check the sign of $g(x)$ for every root.

Answer (score 2):

- $g(x)>0$ obviously holds for $x<0$
- Since we have $g(x)=(x^4+1)x(x-1)+3$ , we have $g(x)>0$ for $x>1$
- For $\ 0\le x\le 1\ $ the minimum of $\ x(x-1)\ $ is $\ -\frac{1}{4}\ $ and $\ x(x-1)\ $ is non-positive whereas $\ x^4+1\ $ is positve and at most $\ 2\ $. Hence $$|(x^4+1)x(x-1)|\le \frac{1}{2}$$ for $\ 0\le x\le 1\ $ which shows that $\ [0,1]\ $ contains no root either.

Answer (score 1):

Consider three cases:

1. $x < 0$: Then:

$$g(x)=x^6+(-x^5)+x^2+(-x)+3 > 0$$

2. $x \in [0,1]$: Then:

$$g(x)=x^6+x^2+(3-x^5-x) > 0$$

3. $x > 1:$ Then:

$$g(x)=x^5(x-1)+x(x-1)+3 > 0$$